# Python Web Scraping: Unable to extract text from bs4 element

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was trying to extract Name and University Seat number from a webpage but I'm getting the following result-

```
[<p class="card-title page-title mb-0 mt-0">Agnello Fernandes A <span class="text-muted">(1sp15me001)</span></p>]
```

which is a bs4 element. I need to extract 'Agnello Fernandes A' and 1sp15me001.

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("http://cbcs.fastvturesults.com/student/1sp15me001")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
all[0].find_all("p",{"class":"card-title page-title mb-0 mt-0"})
```

How can I convert this to an str element and extract the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://cbcs.fastvturesults.com/student/1sp15me001")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
items = soup.find(class_="text-muted")
print("{}\n{}".format(items.previous_sibling,items.text))
```

Output:

```
Agnello Fernandes A 
(1sp15me001)
```

Comment: In case you dont like braces then try using `items.text.replace("(","").replace(")","")`